# Stop on first test failure with `go test`

Tags: unit-testing, go

How do I have `go test several/packages/...` stop after the first test failure?

It takes some time to build and execute the rest of the tests, despite already having something to work with.

Comment: I think you will have to unroll the invocation yourself by running go test on each package and stopping the loop. I doubt there is a flag to do what you want.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go 1.10 added a new flag `failfast` to go test:

The new go test `-failfast` flag disables running additional tests after any test fails. Note that tests running in parallel with the failing test are allowed to complete.

https://golang.org/doc/go1.10

However, note this does not work *across* packages: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33038

Here's a workaround:

```
for s in $(go list ./...); do if ! go test -failfast -v -p 1 $s; then break; fi; done
```

Answer (score -6):

To speed-up the build phase you can run

```
go test -i several/packages/...
```

before the tests to build and install packages that are dependencies of the test.

To stop after the first failure you can use something like

```
go test several/packages/... | grep FAILED | head -n 1
```

Comment: Your second suggestion still runs all the tests, but just doesn't print them out.

Comment: To be honest I haven't tested it with `go test` but if it is implemented in the same way as other Unix utilities it should be terminated via SIGPIPE on the first occurence of FAILED.

Comment: @kostya I have never heared about this tehnique of IPC... thanx