# How to abort testing if critical tests fail

Tags: go, testify

In Go, is there a way to abort a suite of tests early if one of them fails?

I am using [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) suites but this just builds on the basic go [testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) functionality.

Some options I have considered:

- I looked at setting testing.failFast but it is not exported.
- os.Exit() is not recommended, because it could mess up the test output among other things.
- stop on first failure is not sufficient as the first failure might not be in a critical test

I can add my own flag and then add to each test:

```
if criticalTestFailed {
    t.skipTest()
}
```

But this is repetitive and annoying boilerplate to add to each test. What I want is something like:

```
func (suite *MySuite) TestCritcalTest() {
   t := MySuite.T()
   defer func() {
      if t.Failed() {
          MySuite.SkipRemainingTests() //does not exist    
      }
   }()

   // some tests here...
}
```

Is there a common practice here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop on first test failure with \`go test\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046192/stop-on-first-test-failure-with-go-test)

Comment: Or do you want it only for specific tests?

Comment: That doesn't help as the first test to fail is not necessarily a critical test.

Comment: `panic()` may be better than `os.Exit()` as at least deferred functions are run.  I would have thought testing would continue after a test panics but it does not seem to in a test I did.

Comment: You can use [`FailNow`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert?tab=doc#FailNow)

Comment: I don't think that it is possible directly. On the other hand, you might consider wrapping the running of the tests in a script (shell, make, whatever). The script would run first the critical test and stop if that one fails, or continue running the other tests if the critical one passes.

Comment: @SystemGlitch FailNow terminates the current test not the whole test suite.

Answer (score 2):

> The new `go test -failfast` flag disables running additional tests after any test fails. Note that tests running in parallel with the failing test are allowed to complete.
>     --from the golang [website](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#test)

```
go test -failfast
```